# ValueError not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2) - Django

Tags: python, django, api

I have this view:

```
def getData():
    response = requests.get("https://path.to/api/")
    data = response.json()
    random_data = [MyModel(name=name, street=street, email=email, phone=phone) \
     for name, street, email, phone, in data.items()]
    MyModel.objects.bulk_create(random_data)

@require_http_methods(['GET', 'POST'])
def index(request):
    datas = getData()
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

When I access the specified url for `index` method, it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py", line 40, in inner
return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/django_projects/myproj/myproj/user/views.py", line 29, in index
datas = getData()
File "/home/user/django_projects/myproj/myproj/user/views.py", line 18, in getData
for name, street, email, phone, in data.items()]
File "/home/user/django_projects/myproj/myproj/user/views.py", line 18, in <listcomp>
for name, street, email, phone, in data.items()]
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)
[18/Aug/2019 15:18:05] "GET /api/index/ HTTP/1.1" 500 85435
Method Not Allowed (HEAD): /api/index/
```

From this error, I think that the resulting json response from the api might be the problem, since some of these items are kind of `nested` into the resulting `json`

Here's an example response:

[random](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=79494daee0b747f992182026250117b8)

Any ideas?

Comment: Django or django DRF are you using?

Comment: Django, the api decorator is a standard Django one

Comment: i think requests.get("https://path.to/api/") this request not getting required values in list comprehension, check in your model objects are saved?

Comment: I imagine that, but how can I? I mean, its probably becaus of the resulting json, some of these items are nested, so, theres something about that i guess, there is a link with an example from the original url

Comment: indeed you have to find the values in the nested response, you cannot unpack the json object directly like that, and you may need to concatenate some values, like the name for example

Comment: Thank You, Any example you could give me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you check this solution !!

```
def getData():
    response = requests.get("https://path.to/api/")
    data = response.json()
    random_data = [MyModel(name=x['name']['first'], streer=x['location']['street'], email=x['email'], phone=x['phone']) for x  in data['results']]
    MyModel.objects.bulk_create(random_data)
```

Comment: Thanks! On the model? Then the comprehensive list on the view right? Gonna try :)

Comment: Added the __init__ to my model, then changed the random_data = to your comprehensive list, and it says, 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attname'' Do you want me to edit my question? Thank you very much

Comment: No no my MyModel is simple python class to verify data in getting in list compressions so you have to replace the random_data line, i edited my answer pleasecheck

Comment: Awesome mate!, Thank You!